# Apache SSL Redirect Dropping Slash for Subdirectories

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl

Apache 2.4. I am trying to redirect http to https for any requests to my virtual host, including the full path.

I have tried the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.mysite.com
    Redirect permanent / https://sub.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine if I go to http://sub.mysite.com or http.sub.mysite.com/ . But if I go to http://sub.mysite.com/directory I get redirected to https://sub.mysite.comdirectory .

I've been searching google for a while and nothing I have found seems to work. I just want to redirect every http request for anything at sub.mysite.com to go to the identical path with https.

Answer (score 6):

Add a trailing slash to your redirection:
`Redirect permanent / https://sub.mysite.com/`

And when you try again, be aware your browser certainly keep the bad 301 redirection in cache. It could avoid you headaches. To be sure to locate your problem, try to visit your website with another browser, or use curl.

Comment: Thanks for the cache tip, it did cause me headaches.